Question on Principal Ideals
I've recently begun with Frazer Jarvis' Algebraic Number Theory, and on page 88 (pdf) of the text there's this exercise:
Let R = $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, and consider the ideal $\mathfrak{a} = \langle 2, 1 + \sqrt{-5}\rangle$.

By calculating the general element $2\beta + (1 + \sqrt{-5})\gamma$ in $\mathfrak{a}$ (where $\beta, \gamma \in R$), show that every element $a + b\sqrt{-5} \in \mathfrak{a} \text{ with } a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ has the property that $a \equiv b \bmod{2}$. Deduce that $1 \notin \mathfrak{a}$.
Show that if $\mathfrak{a} = \langle \alpha \rangle$, then $N(\alpha)\mid 2$, and  $\mathfrak{a}$ is not principal.

I think I've proven the first part, but assuming the results in the first question are true, I'm not particularly sure about the second one. An earlier result in the book shows that nothing in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ has a norm of 2, and I know that $\alpha$ can't be a unit, since otherwise the ideal would be the ring. Any help on the matter would be appreciated, so thank you.

Use the fact that $\alpha | \beta$ in $R$ implies $N(\alpha) | N(\beta)$ in $\Bbb Z$. Consider more than one $\beta$.

You are on the right track and everything that you have mentioned is relevant.
Suppose $a = \langle \alpha \rangle$ for some $\alpha \in R$. Then $\alpha$ must divide both $2$ and $1 + \sqrt{-5}$ in $R$, and, using what @François Gatine commented, this implies that $N(\alpha)$ divides $N(2) = 2^2 = 4$ and $N(1 + \sqrt{-5}) = 1^2 + 5 \cdot 1^2  = 6$.
Then $N( \alpha )$ divides $\gcd (4,6) = 2$. So $N( \alpha )$ is either $1$ or $2$. If $N(\alpha) = 1$, then $\alpha$ is a unit (not possible, as you mentioned, because $a$ would be the ring), contradiction. If $N(\alpha) = 2$ (not possible, using $N (\alpha) = a^2 + 5b^2$), contradiction.
We conclude that $a$ cannot be principal.
